# Package caption Warning: Unknown document class (or package), standard defaults will be used. How to solve

Tags: tables, floats, subfloats

Package caption Warning: Unknown document class (or package), standard defaults will be used. See the caption package documentation for explanation.
[image]

May I ask, what is the error above, here is my code before document. I need to put the caption of the table in the middle.

```
%\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage[skip=0.5\baselineskip,skip=0.5\abovecaptionskip]{caption}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\usepackage{verbatim}
% \usepackage{subfiles}
\hyphenation{presents}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{3pt}
\date{February 2022}
%%% journal %%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Elsevier bibliography styles
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% To change the style, put a % in front of the second line of the current style and
%% remove the % from the second line of the style you would like to use.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% Numbered
%\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}

%% Numbered without titles
%\bibliographystyle{model1a-num-names}

%% Harvard
%\bibliographystyle{model2-names.bst}\biboptions{authoryear}

%% Vancouver numbered
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model3-num-names}

%% Vancouver name/year
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model4-names}\biboptions{authoryear}

%% APA style
%\bibliographystyle{model5-names}\biboptions{authoryear}

%% AMA style
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model6-num-names}

%% 'Elsevier LaTeX' style
%\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{3pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{3pt} %%% 3pt 

\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{3pt}
\begin{document}
```

Comment: Your code (after completing it) works fine. Tested with my recent version of MiKTeX.

Comment: In Overleaf (which that warning appears to be from), I don't get a warning about the caption package.  I do get an error about the sn-jnl class.

Comment: It just means that the `caption` package doesn't know the document class `sn-jnl`, so it can't do anything special in case that class requires it. For example if `sn-jnl` uses a particular layout for captions, the `caption` package can't take that into account. Probably this is a rather innocent warning.

Comment: I thought specifying the option `style=base` via `\usepackage[style= base]{caption}` or `\captionsetup{style=base}` would eliminate the warning but it does not. Would not it be good to have an option to get rid of the warning once identified the reason for it?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other comments, the caption package does not know the document class `sn-jnl`. One option to avoid the warning is to use the `silence` package to hide the warning by putting this snippet above the `\usepackage{caption}` line.

```latex
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{caption}{Unknown document class (or package)}
```

Comment: In many cases, that is the best solution. If the Warning has other consequences, they will still be seen.